# CheckStyle module prevent "too many" carriage returns?

Tags: checkstyle

Is there a CheckStyle module that will mimic the behavior below?

For Java + IntelliJ.

With StyleCop, it will natively check for "too many" carriage returns.

Sample C# code:

Notice the lines BELOW "using System.Collections.Generic" and ABOVE the method "GetSingle" .. they have more-than-one-empty line.

StyleCop would complain, and you would fix by having 1 or 0 empty lines in that space.

I couldn't find anything  at : https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/config_whitespace.html

Or i don't know what the magic word is for what I'm looking for.

```
namespace Examples.UnitTestingWithInMemoryLoggingExample.SimulatedProject.Bal.Managers
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;



    using Examples.UnitTestingWithInMemoryLoggingExample.SimulatedProject.Bal.Managers.Interfaces;
    using Examples.UnitTestingWithInMemoryLoggingExample.SimulatedProject.Dal.Interfaces;
    using Examples.UnitTestingWithInMemoryLoggingExample.SimulatedProject.Domain;
    using Surescripts.Components.Logging.LoggingAbstractBase;

    public class EmployeeManager : IEmployeeManager
    {
        public const string ErrorMessageILoggerFactoryWrapperIsNull = "ILoggerFactoryWrapper is null";
        public const string ErrorMessageIEmployeeDataIsNull = "IEmployeeData is null";

        public const string LogMsgEmployeeManagerGetAll = "EmployeeManager.GetAll started";
        public const string LogMsgEmployeeManagerGetSingle = "EmployeeManager.GetSingle started (key='{0}')";
        public const string LogMsgKeyLessThanZero = "Warning Warning Warning.  Key less than zero. (key='{0}')";

        private readonly ILoggerWrapper<EmployeeManager> logger;
        private readonly IEmployeeData empData;

        public EmployeeManager(ILoggerFactoryWrapper loggerFactory, IEmployeeData empData)
        {
            if (null == loggerFactory)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException(ErrorMessageILoggerFactoryWrapperIsNull, (Exception)null);
            }

            this.logger = loggerFactory.CreateLoggerWrapper<EmployeeManager>();
            this.empData = empData ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(ErrorMessageIEmployeeDataIsNull, (Exception)null);
        }

        public ICollection<Employee> GetAll()
        {
            this.logger.LogInformation(LogMsgEmployeeManagerGetAll);
            ICollection<Employee> returnItems = this.empData.GetAll();
            return returnItems;
        }





        public Employee GetSingle(long key)
        {
            this.logger.LogInformation(string.Format(LogMsgEmployeeManagerGetSingle, key));

            if (key < 0)
            {
                /* simple example to show IsEnabled */
                if (this.logger.IsEnabled(LoggingEventTypeEnum.Warning))
                {
                    this.logger.Log(new LogEntry(LoggingEventTypeEnum.Warning, string.Format(LogMsgKeyLessThanZero, key)));
                }
            }

            Employee returnItem = this.empData.GetSingle(key);
            return returnItem;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Found it

```
<module name="EmptyLineSeparator">
      <property name="allowMultipleEmptyLines" value="false"/>
    </module>
```